# Plugin issue with ionic 3 app

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building a set wallpaper ionic 3 app. I'm facing 3 main issues with the ionic app.

1. Side menu swipe not working in real Android device or emulator. Only working in ionic serve --lab in chrome browser.
2. Touch ripple not working in real Android device or emulator. Only working in ionic serve --lab in chrome browser.
3. Set wallpaper cordova plugin not working.

I tried searching this problems in ionic forums but with no luck. The plugin that I use is: cordova-plugin-wallpaper(https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-wallpaper). I followed their steps but still no output.

I changed TypeScript code, used 'any' (Doc was about older version of Ionic which used JavaScript), but the problem still exists. Also tried changing clobber tag in plugin xml.

When set wallpaper button is pressed showing "Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'wallpaper' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'wallpaper' of undefined" in ionic serve --lab chrome browser.

Link to test1 ionic 3 app project in Google Drive (node_modules folder is not included because of the large size):https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxZZQyYJypvRMk1rN2stX2ppX2s

HTML:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="dark">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>appname</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
                <ion-card>
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ16sUl5EqIDeuP1AjIX6ESSbAFAcS2-JLr4znf-extlfIr47Ni"/>
                    <div>wallpaper</div>
                    <button ion-button small class='downl' (click)="setWall()">
                      Download</button>     
                  </ion-card>
     </ion-content>
```

TypeScript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var window: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {

  }

  setWall() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        var setImg = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ16sUl5EqIDeuP1AjIX6ESSbAFAcS2-JLr4znf-extlfIr47Ni";

        window.plugins.wallpaper.setImageHttp(setImg, function(error) {
          if (error) {
            console.error(error);
         } else {
             console.log('Success setting wallpaper.');
         }
      });
    });
}

}
```

What is the real issue here?

Comment: the issue is you are trying to use a cordova plugin in `ionic serve` where cordova is not supported. You need to test this using device/emulator

Comment: I also did that in device/emulator,when set wallpaper button is pressed nothing happens in the app.

Comment: no errors in console when you tried in device?

Comment: anything wrong in plugin folder?

Comment: Can you tell me about side menu swipe problem and touch ripple problem?

Comment: try `declare var wallpaper: any;` and call as `wallpaper.setImageHttp`

Comment: Is that because of clobbers defined like that in plugin xml?

Comment: I think so..yes.. otherwise you just have to raise an issue and wait for them to respond

Comment: I actually tried that before you said to tried it,it was not working.Now also not working.

Comment: Plugin doc say to use window.plugins.wallpaper.setImg to set wallpaper.